# Akka cluster sharding configuration

Tags: scala, akka, cluster-computing

Ok, I have 2 instances of my backend, hosted on 2 difference centos servers. What I want to do using `Akka Cluster Sharding` is to divide the work done by each of these instances:

- I have data for 4 countries, which is retrieved from db at every 10 seconds by both backend instances, which update a `Redis` instance. So, multiple times, I have duplicated requests, because both backends get data for same country;
- Using `Akka Cluster Sharding`, I try to divide the work dinamically, `instance1` to get data for ES and EN, `instance2` to get data for DE and IT. In case of instance1 is down, instance2 will take the jobs and will get data even for ES/EN.

I tought this is simple...but not.

All jobs are done by Akka Actors, so using Cluster Sharding, I thought all declared actors (from both instances) will be centralized somewhere, to can manipulate which do whatever job.

On localhost, all works fine, because I have an instance for my app with port `9001` and 2 cluster nodes with ports `2551` and `2552`. But for production, I can't understand how to configure the `hostnames`

application.conf

```
"clusterRegistration" {
    akka {
      actor {
        allow-java-serialization = on
        provider = cluster
      }
      remote.artery {
        enabled = on
        transport = aeron-udp
      }
      cluster {
        jmx.multi-mbeans-in-same-jvm = on
        seed-nodes = [
            "akka://ClusterService@instance1:8083",
            "akka://ClusterService@instance1:2551"
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

class

```
object ClusterSharding {
  def createNode(hostname: String, port: Int, role: String, props: Props, actorName: String) = {
    val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(
      s"""
         |akka.cluster.roles = ["$role"]
         |akka.remote.artery.canonical.hostname = $hostname
         |akka.remote.artery.canonical.port = $port
         |""".stripMargin
    ).withFallback(ConfigFactory.load
      .getConfig("clusterRegistration"))

    val system = ActorSystem("ClusterService", config)
    system.actorOf(props, actorName)
  }

  val master = createNode("instance1", 8083, "master", Props[Master], "master")
  createNode("instance1", 2551, "worker", Props[Worker], "worker")
  createNode("instance2", 8083, "worker", Props[Worker], "worker")

  Future {
    while (true) {
      master ! Proceed // this will fire an Actor Resolver case
      Thread.sleep(5000)
    }
  }
}
```

master actor

```
class Master extends Actor {
  var workers: Map[Address, ActorRef] = Map()
 
  val cluster = Cluster(context.system)
 
  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    cluster.subscribe(
      self,
      initialStateMode = InitialStateAsEvents,
      classOf[MemberEvent],
      classOf[UnreachableMember]
    )
  }

  override def postStop(): Unit = {
    cluster.unsubscribe(self)
  }
  def receive = handleClusterEvents // cluster events
    .orElse(handleWorkerRegistration) // worker registered to cluster
    .orElse(handleJob) // give jobs to workers

  def handleJob: Receive = {
    case Proceed => {
       // Here I must be able to use all workers from both instances 
       // (centos1 and centos2) and give work for each dinamically
         if (workers.length == 2) {
           worker1 ! List("EN", "ES")
           worker2 ! List("DE", "IT")
         } else if (workers.length == 1) {
           worker ! List("EN", "ES", "DE", "IT")
         } else {
            execQueries() // if no worker is available, each backend instance will exec queries on his own way
         }
    }
  }
}
```

Both instances are hosted with port 8083 (centos1: `instance1:8083`, centos2: `instance2:8083`). If I use settings just for one of the instances in application.conf and in createNode (instance1 for example), I can see in logs that the workers are created, but there is no communication with the second instance.

Where I'm wrong? thx

Comment: Is your goal to implement your own cluster sharding or to use Akka's cluster sharding?

Comment: If your workers are just going to be updating Redis, I would strongly suggest to use Sharded Daemon Process.

Comment: It does seem like you're confused about what cluster sharding is.

Comment: Yes, I'm a bit confuse if `Cluster Sharding` is what I need to solve this problem. For moment yes, is needed only for update the data on a `Redis` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to configuring the hostnames is viable.  There are better ways to do it (depending on how you're deploying the service: manual deploy vs. ansible/chef/puppet vs. docker vs. kubernetes/nomad/mesos will be different), but setting the hostname isn't likely your actual problem.

Your current approach will give you a master and 2 workers on every node and you're not actually using Cluster Sharding (you're using Cluster, but Cluster Sharding is something you opt into on top of Cluster).  From the code you've posted, I strongly suspect that using Cluster Sharding will entail a dramatic redesign (though without posting the `Worker` and more complete `Master` code, it's hard to say).

The broad approach I'd take with this would be to have the process of updating Redis for a given country be owned by a sharded entity (keyed by that country).  A cluster singleton actor would trigger the update process for each country every 10 seconds.  Because we're using sharding and singleton, I'd probably actually have at least 3 instances of the service, or alternatively make use of a strongly consistent external lease system (the other split-brain resolution strategies (note that cluster sharding and cluster singleton basically force you to resolve split-brains) will all boil down, at least half the time, to losing one node is the same as losing both in a 2-node cluster).  Because sharding implies that the actor for a process could be stopped arbitrarily (and possibly resumed on a different node), you'll also want to think about how the process can be resumed in a way that makes sense for the application.

Starting multiple `ActorSystem`s in the same JVM process is generally only a good idea in fairly specific circumstances.